# Is there a Ping Module?

Tags: 7

I'm creating a support site for a hosting company in D7 and one of the features that they have asked for is for drupal to ping each of the servers, (I have a content type called Server which has ipaddresses attached to it) and report back the status.  I want to set it up as cron job.  Is there a module for Drupal that I can add that gives me this feature?  if not can you give me any pointers how to get started on building one?

Thanks

Kieran Briggs

Comment: Are you looking to trigger an ICMP ping, check that a [L|M|W]AMP stack is responsive or something else?

Comment: Can't you just export the IP lists and have a cron job do the rest? Views Data Export might help you export a list of IPs.

Comment: If I did that how would I get the results back into Drupal to display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [multiping](http://drupal.org/project/multiping) module will provide this feature in Drupal 7, since the [ping](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/ping) module is not part of core anymore. The D7 branch hasn't been started, but there is a [patch](http://drupal.org/node/1095740#comment-5307718) that you can test that ports the module to Drupal 7. If you test it and it works for you, please comment on that issue, the more people that review that patch the closer the module will get to a full D7 release.

Answer (score 0):

The [Ping module](https://www.drupal.org/project/ping) seems like a good and supported solution for Drupal 7.